# Timezone convert

Tags: javascript, php, timezone

this is my requirement.website admin add a time to an event. Then users will see that time according to user's current location time.

And this php code to convert any time to user current location's time.

```
<?php
    $date = date_create('2000-01-01',timezone_open('Pacific/Nauru'));
    date_timezone_set($date,timezone_open('Europe/Moscow'));
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

How to determine user timezone (ex:Europe/Moscow)

I have this js code to get timezone of user current location.

```
<script>
    var visitortime = new Date();
    var time = visitortime.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
    alert(time);
</script>
```

But it alert a number(ex:+5.5) 
Can you help me please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to get current users timezone.

```
var timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
```